# AppCenter build failing for Xamarin.Forms android project error: Could not locate the assembly "Mono.Android"

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

I can build my application in Debug and Release mode locally but the build fails on Appcenter. When I clone my proeject to a different local folder and run it, everything works, so there seems to be an issue only when I deploy it to Appcenter. I have turned off all the settings possible in my Appcenter build settings for my Xamarin.Forms android project. In my build settings in Appcenter I have selected SDK version: Xamarin.Android 9.3 (which I am slightly confused as to what this does) and have set the mode to Release just like my local project.

I end up with a bunch of errors but the three main ones that stand out to me are:

warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Mono.Android".
error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly '[App name].Android
error MSB4018: File name: '[App name].Android.dll'

I have tried changing my target android version to be the latest (Pie 9.0) as opposed to Oreo 8.1. I have tried Linking: Sdk Assemblies Only, Sdk and user assemblies, and none (which are all the possible options for Linker properties). I have tried supporting armeabi-47, x86 originally then tried adding arm64 and x86_64.

```
<PackageReference Include="CarouselView.FormsPlugin" Version="5.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.2.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Plugin.Permissions" Version="3.0.0.12" />
<PackageReference Include="PropertyChanged.Fody" Version="3.0.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Rg.Plugins.Popup" Version="1.1.5.188" />
<PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.Media" Version="4.0.1.5" />
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.1.0.618606" />  
<PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="1.2.0" />  
<PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile" Version="2.4.1" />  
<PackageReference Include="ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms" Version="2.4.1" />
```

Expected: building in Appcenter works like it does on my cleaned local machine.

Actual: I receive error codes in Appcenter logs:

- error MSB4018: The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
- error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load
  assembly [App name].Android
- error MSB4018: File name: '[App name].Android.dll'
- error MSB4018:   at
  Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve
- error MSB4018: at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute
- warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
  the assembly "Mono.Android".

Error CS0246 the type or namespace name could not be found for:

- 'UsesFeatureAttribute', 'UsesFeature', 'Required', 'Android'

Comment: Here is the article about building xamarin app, you can take a look: https://www.ecanarys.com/Blogs/ArticleID/338/App-Center-With-Xamarin-Forms

Comment: I have done all of this sadly, but to no avail. I have built other apps with Xamarin.Android on AppCenter and they've built fine in the past, but for some reason, my new project is failing almost regardless of what I put in the build settings of appcenter.

Answer (score 1):

I was referencing Android specific assembly code in my shared project's AssemblyInfo.cs file. I removed that code and remove this ItemGroup (which was generated because of that code) from my shared project's csproj file. Everything work just fine on AppCenter after that.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I am having the same error. If I removed that my solution doesn't build locally. Was this the case for you also? Thx

Comment: I was able to run both locally and remotely (in AppCenter) once I removed this code from my shared project. I would perhaps look into why your shared project requires a reference to Mono.Android in it's assembly. Maybe a third-party package you downloaded requires it?

Comment: Yes I need to reference MonoAndroid.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I believe this happens in the case where your iOS project is selected to build but it fails, even though you may specify building only an iOS project, the NuGet restore step does a restore for ALL projects in the solution of the project you've specified, including any Android projects in the solution. Presumably this is the same on Android but I haven't checked yet.

This has cropped up recently because the Azure DevOps macOS-13 image (which is what you are running on if you select the latest mono in the build configuration, and you see that it will use XCode 15.0.1 preview) does not have Xamarin installed by default.

The build scripts will install Xamarin.iOS in this case, but since they never install Xamarin.Android, that NuGet restore of all projects in the solution fails.

Since you can't prevent these build scripts from running, you have to work around this by either:

1. Installing Xamarin.Android
2. Remove the Android projects from the solution

Either one of these requires a custom post-clone build script, because that's the only point in which you can do something before the NuGet restore step.